# Remove a (non-master) collection without deleting objects via script

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of right-clicking on a scene collection, and selecting 'DELETE', which removes the collection but does not remove any of the objects.

However, all functions and answers I found (unlink, collection.remove, etc) always remove all the objects that are part of the collection, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to relink the objects to a new collection.  Here's an example that removes all the objects from a collection called "monkeys" and moves them to the default collection while removing "monkeys".  Change the names to protect your innocent:

```py
import bpy

collection_to_remove = bpy.data.collections.get('monkeys')

objects_from_collection = [object for object in collection_to_remove.objects]
bpy.data.collections.remove(collection_to_remove)

collection_to_link_to = bpy.data.collections.get('Collection')
for object in objects_from_collection:
    collection_to_link_to.objects.link(object)
```